# expo-service-worker.js: 93 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope':

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my react-native project on my console, when I "expo start --web" when the application is open in the chrome I have this error in the console

`expo-service-worker.js: 93 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http: // localhost: 19006 / service-worker.js' failed to load. at http: // localhost: 19006 / expo-service-worker.js: 93: 6 (anonymous) @ expo-service-worker.js: 93 The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text / html')."`

Comment: I got the same error, it work fine when accessing from the ip instead of localhost, but you'll have a weaker permissions level unless if you have https.

Comment: please how i can access my project via ip ?

Comment: To get your ip, it depend on your os. To access it via ip, just use it in your url instead of `localhost`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, can i ask you other things please?